# How do I add a timestamp to the SQL table, then echo the latest row by time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a working script which echoes out data from the SQL DB. I am wondering how I would add a way to record the time the row was added then subsequently echo the latest row to my table. You can see for an example on my website [HERE](http://scntrx.co.uk).

I want the latest row to show at the top, not the bottom. I'm sure there is an easy solution, but as you can tell I am only just learning this. Thanks if anybody has a solution. I have tried sorting by DESC and ASC in the SQL query but that's sorting it by alphabetical order and I need it to show the latest row of the table at the top.

Comment: Just use SQL's `NOW()` function and add a DATETIME column to your table upon `INSERT`. *"I am wondering how I would add a way to record the time the row was added."*

Comment: Add with `ALTER TABLE` a column i.e. `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Create a TIMESTAMP column with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then ORDER your queries, and possibly LIMIT them.

Answer (score 1):

The way you add a default "creation date" onto a record is well described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).  The code looks something like:

```
alter table <tablename> add CreatedAt datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

(or even better do it in the `create table` statement).  I usually name such a column `CreatedAt`.  Then I sometimes have `CreatedBy` (for the user) and `CreatedOn` (for the system).

To fetch the results:

```
select *
from <tablename> t
order by CreatedAt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column in your database table like `time` (with DATETIME datatype) and in your insert query `time = NOW()`. When your try to fetch the data from database do like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to use the time=NOW() in my insert query?

Comment: You don't have to if your MySQL version is 5.6.5 or newer and you're using DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as proposed by some of us.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO table_name (time) VALUES (NOW())";` or you can also use php datatime. `$datatime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); "INSERT INTO table_name (time) VALUES ('$datetime')";`

Comment: @VMai I just saw your reply, it's working now! Thanks sir.